# Cannot remove "-" sign in textBox with Guid type in C#

Tags: c#

I have 1 function to gennerate Guid Id for my application.

```
Guid IDRF = new Guid(txtID.Text.ToString());
```

I want `txtID` contain generate like `07bceb9ef1ca49d79b0dacdccff80406` instead of `07bceb9e-f1ca-49d7-9b0d-acdccff80406`.

In other function:

```
mReader.CurrentCardIDBlock1 = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
```

I use ("N") to remove "-" sign.

But I don't know how to remove "-" character in TextBox txtID.

Edit: Thank you. My problem is solve.

```
string stringID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
string ID = stringID;
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Don't thank the user for the answer, just accept it !

Comment: You haven't accepted any answer to any of your questions.  @TyreeJackson answered this question correctly, so you "should" click the check mark next to his answer so this question is solved.  You should also do the same for you other questions, if they have been successfully answer.

Comment: So sorry, today I look button appcept below button thanks. I was appcept and all question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guids don't actually contain a hyphen.  They are just presented that way.  A Guid is stored in memory as an 16 byte, 128 bit structure.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx for more information.  The hyphen only appears when you view a Guid as a string in it's default format.

If you are wanting to present a Guid without the hyphens in a textbox, use something like the following:

```
Guid someGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
txtID.Text = someGuid.ToString("N");
```